# Apache Test Page Shows on External IP

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, httpd

If you use the external IP address in your browser for one of our sites, it displays the Apache test page rather than redirecting back to the domain name.  Our other sites redirect back to the domain as expected, but this one in particular doesn't (about 40 servers in total).

I've disabled welcome.conf but we get a 403 instead.

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Are you using [virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/)? What happens when you browse to 127.0.0.1 on the machine running Apache? Last question - when you say about 40 servers in total, do you mean 40 domains?

Comment: I mean, 40 servers server1.whatever.local server2.whatever.local etc.  In total there are about 25 ecommerce websites and it's a live environment so I'm hoping it's something that can be done with a graceful restart.  Yes, we're using vhosts.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by 40 server. Do you mean you have 40 separate machines running? It sounds like you have 40 separate domains, all pointing to the same server.

Comment: 40 virtual machines, load balanced across about 25 websites.

Comment: Some of those words don't make sense in the order that you wrote them. Please describe your situation more clearly.

Comment: In total, we have about 40 virtual machines across our physical servers.  We have in the region of 25 websites which are stored in blocks (server 1, 2 3, 4 is Block A, server 5, 6, 7, 8 is Block B etc.).  We have several websites per block, for instance website1.com website2.com website3.com are on Block A, website 4, webiste 5 are on Block B.  These are load balanced so that traffic alternates between different servers.  We also use vhosts.  On one particular website, if we put the external ip address of the virtual server into the web browser, it takes you to the Apache test page.

Comment: Rather than redirecting you to the domain name.